# Core data repeat saves the same variables

Tags: swift, core-data

I have been having a tough time finding the proper way to save a var into core data and pull it out so this is how I have done it. The problem is since I have pulled it out and saved it again it has more than one save of the same variable which leads to it duplicating every time i want to save. Does anyone have recommendations on the proper way to do this? Thanks in advance

There is a button (saveButton) that appends an array and defines two variables (age) and (name) attached to the Core Data Entity class Person. It then saves it in core data. Now on startup I append the array for every one in Core Data and define each variable attached with it.

```
var list = [Person]()

@IBAction func saveButton(_ sender: Any)
{
    list.append(NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName:"Person", into:context ) as! Person)

    list[list.count-1].age = Int16(ageTF.text!)!
    list[list.count-1].name = nameTF.text

    appDelegate.saveContext()
}

@IBAction func printList(_ sender: Any)
{

    for index in 0...list.count-1
    {
        print("Name of person # \(index) = \(list[index].name!)")
        print("Age of person # \(index) = \(list[index].age)")
    }

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    do {
        let results = try context.fetch(Person.fetchRequest())
        let listItems = results as! [Person]

        for lists in listItems
        {
            print(lists.age)
            print(lists.name!)

            list.append(NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName:"Person", into:context ) as! Person)

            list[list.count-1].age = lists.age
            list[list.count-1].name = lists.name

        }
    }
    catch {
        print("Error")

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you're hoping this will work, but your `viewDidLoad` method looks like trouble.

First it does this:

```
let results = try context.fetch(Person.fetchRequest())
let listItems = results as! [Person]
```

Then for every item in `listItems` it does this:

```
list.append(NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName:"Person", into:context ) as! Person)
```

In other words, you fetch some number of objects from Core Data and then you immediately go and create duplicate entries for every one of them.

I can't figure out what you want to be happening here, but right now it sounds like Core Data is doing exactly what you tell it to do: Create a duplicate instance for every existing object. The obvious fix is *don't do that* but the real answer depends on why you think it's necessary in the first place.

Comment: I never once said its not doing what im telling it to do I said I'm not sure the proper way to do it and that's the closest I got since there seems to be no actual tutorials on this.

Comment: You're saving, and you're fetching. That looks fine. For some reason you wrote code to create duplicate entries. I don't know what you intended to accomplish with that line of code, so I can't tell you how to fix it.

Comment: I'm trying to retrieve the data saved with core data and put it back into the original array on the app startup

Comment: You can update a managedObject by just changing it property and calling save() on the context.